# double combineLatest doesn't emit update

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, angularfire2

In my project there are activities that people have created, joined, bookmarked or organized. I've read a lot of these question already. But most of the code was less complex or people forgot to subscribe...

I would like to get all the activities in a certain time period and then add creator information (name, image, etc) and add booleans if the user retrieving these activities has joined/bookmarked/organized this activity. The code I used before would provide live updates (ex. I join an activity, by adding my userId to the participants array and the activity.joined would update to true).

Previous code:

```
public getActivities(user: UserProfileModel): Observable<Array<ActivityModel>> {
    const now: number = moment().startOf('day').unix();
    const later: number = moment().startOf('day').add(30, 'day').unix();
    return this.afs.collection<ActivityModel>(`cities/${user.city.id}/activities`, ref => ref
        .where('datetime', '>=', now)
        .where('datetime', '<=', later))
        .valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })
        .pipe(
            map(activities => activities.map(activity => {
                const bookmarked = activity.bookmarkers ? activity.bookmarkers.includes(user.uid) : false;
                const joined = activity.participants ? activity.participants.includes(user.uid) : false;
                const organized = activity.organizers ? activity.organizers.includes(user.uid) : false;
                return { bookmarked, joined, organized, ...activity } as ActivityModel;
        }))
    );
}
```

The I wanted to add the creator as an observable object, so their latest changes in name or profile picture would be shown. But with this code change, my getActivities doesn't emit any updates anymore...

My new code:

```
public getActivities(user: UserProfileModel): Observable<Array<CombinedActivityCreatorModel>> {
    const now: number = moment().startOf('day').unix();
    const later: number = moment().startOf('day').add(30, 'day').unix();
    return this.afs.collection<ActivityModel>(`cities/${user.city.id}/activities`, ref => ref
        .where('datetime', '>=', now)
        .where('datetime', '<=', later))
        .valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })
        .pipe(
            concatMap(activities => {
                const completeActivityData = activities.map(activity => {
                    const activityCreator: Observable<UserProfileModel> = this.getCreator(activity.creator);
                    const bookmarked = activity.bookmarkers ? activity.bookmarkers.includes(user.uid) : false;
                    const joined = activity.participants ? activity.participants.includes(user.uid) : false;
                    const organized = activity.organizers ? activity.organizers.includes(user.uid) : false;
                    return combineLatest([
                        of({ bookmarked, joined, organized, ...activity }),
                        activityCreator
                    ]).pipe(
                        map(([activityData, creatorObject]: [ActivityModel, UserProfileModel]) => {
                            return {
                                 ...activityData,
                                 creatorObject: creatorObject
                            } as CombinedActivityCreatorModel;
                        })
                    );
                });
            return combineLatest(completeActivityData);
        })
    );
}
```

The code has become a bit complex, that I don't see the solution myself. Anybody that can offer some assistance?

Comment: Does the observable returned by `this.getCreator` complete ?

Comment: I do think it completes. See my answer to satanTime below.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like one of `activityCreator` doesn't emit a value, combineLatest requires all observables to emit at least once.

I would recommend you to debug how `activityCreator` behaves.
If it's fine that it doesn't emit you have 2 options: `startWith` to set a value for an initial emit, or `defaultIfEmpty`, it emits in case if stream is going to be closed without any emit.

```js
activityCreator = this.getCreator(activity.creator).pipe(
  // startWith(null), // for example if you want to trigger combineLatest.
  // defaultIfEmpty(null), // in case of an empty stream.
);
```

---

another thing is `concatMap` it requires an observable to complete, only then it switches to the next one, parhaps `mergeMap` or `switchMap` fits here better.

Try the code below and add its output to the comments. Thanks.

```js
                        const activityCreator: Observable<UserProfileModel> = this.getCreator(activity.creator).pipe(
                            tap(
                                () => console.log('getCreator:emit'),
                                () => console.log('getCreator:error'),
                                () => console.log('getCreator:completed'),
                            ),
                        );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've changed the line to:
const activityCreator: Observable<UserProfileModel> = this.getCreator(activity.creator).pipe(
    startWith(null), // for example if you want to trigger combineLatest.
    defaultIfEmpty(null), // in case of an empty stream.
    tap((creator) => console.log("get creator", creator))
)
In the console I first get null and later the creatorObject. So that seems fine, right?

Comment: yep. `startWith` always emits as the very first instant value. That's why I also suggested `defaultIfEmpty` - it doesn't emit at the beginning but emits if a stream closes without any emit. Depends what fits your requirements better.

Comment: I think my question was a bit unclear. I've added my old code. That code DOES emit updates in the activities array. The new code DOES NOT. What in my new code do you think break this? Can I fix it while keeping observable creator (user) information?

Comment: Got it, I'll check it soon and let you know.

Comment: Might you check the 2nd part of the answer? Was `concatMap` added on a purpose, might you explain it?